# Heroku simple search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

On my local server (rails & MySQL) I can run a simple search like this:

```
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

Where I pass in the search parameter and it tries to match that to the name field in a particular model.  However, I get no results in my application on heroku, and in the heroku console i also get no results.

I know heroku doesn't run MySQL, can anyone explain why this doesn't work and the simplest way around it.

UPDATE:
After playing around and some research (now that I knew where to look), LIKE in MySQL is not case-sensitive. It still works on heroku, but was throwing me off because it is case-sensitive.  ILIKE is solution for deployment on heroku.

Comment: Can you paste any error you get? Did you run migrations?

Comment: I'm sorry, misworded, no error, just no results returned on heroku.  And all migration are run and working.

Comment: Could you try `find(:all, :conditions => ['name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])` instead?

Comment: AHA!  It works!  Is that the equivalent postgresql command?

Comment: ILIKE is for case insensitive searches on Postgres, whereas LIKE is for case sensitive searches.

Comment: Postgres is free, and open source, like MySQL, so you could install it locally instead of using MySQL in the future as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really suggest running Postgres locally if you're deploying to Heroku.  No matter how good your code and tests, if you're deploying to a different stack you're going to see all sorts of problems.

In PG land, you'll need this:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```